# Is it possible to mute a Gmail conversation?

Tags: gmail, mute

**Use case:**

I receive some conversation that after a while are not relevant for me anymore.

I would like to somehow mute them so that they don't arrive as new and unread emails in my inbox anymore.

Is this achievable?

Comment: You can always use a filter to send them into a black hole, though that may be unwise if the same person sends you an email with the same subject that isn't part of the original thread (ie, several months later).

Comment: Hey @orschiro, please unmark your "accepted answer" as it became obsolete by now. The answer for **New Gmail** is [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120929/104287).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **New Gmail** ([introduced in July 2018](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2018/07/new-gmail-ga.html)), it's different:

1. This is the confusing part. There are **two** 3 dots menu items. In New Gmail, only the top one has the Mute option!
   [image: The right menu that allows muting conversations]
2. If you [enable Gmail shortcuts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594), you can click "m" to mute a conversation.

> When you mute a message: Any replies stay out of your inbox. You can search for the conversation if you want to find it again.
>
> <sup>[Google Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576)</sup>

Comment: Be aware that gmail conversations doesn't use the thread headers, it's solely based on subject. Any email with similar subject might also get muted.

Comment: @hultqvist, are you 100% sure? Was it also like this in [Gmail Classic](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90831/104287)? It's pretty weird Google would do something like this without even a warning on their documentation. I would have expected them to at least consider the From/To fields.

Comment: The "new" gmail is not about the mute feature, as you compare your answer to the previous one it's only a change in the user interface. The gmail conversation is bad for people who use similar subject for several emails, threads for separate discussions tend to be grouped together into a single conversation. Since one can assume mute works on conversations it the same rules would apply to the mute feature.

Answer (score 3):

In Gmail, when viewing the conversation, open the "More" menu and choose "Mute".

[image: "More" menu]

From [Google Support <sup>(archived)</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309231633/https://support.google.com/mail/answer/47787):

> Muted conversations will only pop back into your inbox ready for your attention if a new message in the conversation is addressed to you and no one else, or if you're added to the "To" or "Cc" line in a new message.

Comment: Your reply is obsolete by now. [Here's](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120929/104287) how to do it in **New Gmail**.

Answer (score 0):

If you find conversations are popping back into the inbox you can create a new Apps Script (from Google Drive) with the following contents and add a Timed project trigger (most easily available from the classic editor) to run it every 15 minutes:

```
function archiveMuted() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:muted',0,100);
  GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads);
}
```

Adjust the number 100 to the amount of muted email threads you expect in your inbox every 15 minutes.